# The following series with a polynomial as numerator and $e^n$ as denominator converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is the following:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {8n^2-7}{e^n(n+1)^2} $$

Comment: How is $e^n$ the denominator, as your title claims? I would call that "the quotient of a rational function of $n$, and $e^n$", but still would not say that "$e^n$ is the denominator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the ratio test $$u_n=\frac {8n^2-7}{e^n(n+1)^2}$$ $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{(n+1)^2 \left(8 (n+1)^2-7\right)}{e (n+2)^2 \left(8 n^2-7\right)}=\frac 1e \, \frac{8 n^4+32 n^3+41 n^2+18 n+1}{8 n^4+32 n^3+25 n^2-28 n-28}$$ the limit of which being $\frac 1e$.

Answer (score 5):

It converges by comparing it to the convergent geometric series: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n}$

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is any polynomial,
and $c > 1$
then
$\sum \frac{p(n)}{c^n}
$
converges.

The proof can either be done
using the ratio or root test.

For ratio,
if the highest order term
is $n^d$,
$\frac{p(n+1)}{p(n)}
\to \frac{(n+1)^d}{n^d}
=(1+1/n)^d
\to 1
$.

For the root test,
$(p(n)/c^n)^{1/n}
<(an^{d})^{1/n}/c
\to 1/c
< 1
$
since both
$a^{1/n}$
and
$n^{1/n}
\to 1$.